# iframe is not loaded on remote server

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, iframe

i am developing a site where the admin will publish pdf file and the file will be loaded in a html page. i use iframe to do so and it works fine on localhost but when i uploaded in to remote server it force me to download the pdf file.here is my code

```
<iframe src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/2.pdf" width="950px" height="800px" >
```

and [here](http://leatherbusinessbangladesh.com/index.php/pages/ordinary_member)
is the link for the page.please suggest me to fix this problem.

Comment: iframes are a bad idea almost always. in addition i visited the site and it displays as i think you wanted it to. the behaviour sounds browser based

Comment: Well I am seeing it inline... might be a security policy of your browser. Using FF 21. Also the client must have a plugin for allowing him to view it inline, in Windows migth be Adobe reader, I am using Firefox's default.

Comment: multiple better options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/2.pdf');?>" width="950px" height="800px" >
```

Comment: without doing anything your link is works fine..So i think may be it up to browser dependent problem.